# Trello API - how do I get a list of all the board actions for just the visible cards?

Tags: api, trello

I know how to get all the board actions, and I know how to get the visible cards and loop through to get their actions. What I'm hoping to find is a way to combine those so I can make 1 or two calls and get everything I need.

Currently, if I get all the board actions, I get ALL the board actions - including all the cards that have been moved off to other lists/boards or cards that aren't visible anymore.

If I get all the cards, then loop through to get that cards' actions, this is very slow and sometimes will time out.

What I want to do is something like this /boards//actions?filter_cards=visible&etc&etc

This seems to be an obvious gap in the API but perhaps I'm missing something?

Thanks in advance.
Mike

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the actions on a board by using the following API

```
/boards/<your_board_id_here>/actions
```

You can test the same with Trello sandbox (by changing the api url) https://developers.trello.com/sandbox

Comment: Thank you, but how to get board actions was not my question.